# why is there a random bar between my divs

Tags: html, css

So I have no clue why this bar is here:

[image: The random bar that I have colored in blue in paint]

Here is [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4r87q9u/1/). I need to get rid of the yellowish bar.

Here is the same code in a snippet:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff9e8;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #edeff2;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Fresca', sans-serif;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.maincontent {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.infotexta {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.middlebar {
  height: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #edeff2;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-image-front {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>placeholder</title>
  <!-- css -->
  <link href="mainstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">temp</a>
    <a href="#">temp</a>
    <a href="#">temp</a>
  </div>

  <div class="topimage">
    <img src="/users/grecko/desktop/back.png" alt="topimage" class="main-image-front">
  </div>

  <div class="middlebar">

  </div>

  <div class="maincontent">
    <div class="maincontent-about infotexta">
      <h1>placeholder</h1>
      <p>your text hereyour text here<br>your text hereyour text here<br>your text hereyour text here<br>your text hereyour text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
```

Edit: the JSFiddle shows alt text for the image cause I forgot I have the image on my PC but you can still see the line.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting your topnav margins? They are possibly not set to 0

Comment: Can you be more clear what you are trying to get rid of? Your screen shot doesn't match your fiddle.

Comment: @greckoDev so did any answer help you to achieve your goal or you still have problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a height on your image and then set the same height on the container. 
https://jsfiddle.net/o4r87q9u/3/

```
.topimage img {
  height: 200px;
}

.topimage {
  height: 200px;
}
```

---

**Before**
[image: before]

---

**After**
[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

The yellowish bar is showing because you have an image inside of it.

If you want to overlay your image in the following blue bar, you can set `.topimage` to `position:absolute`

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #fff9e8;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #edeff2;
    overflow: hidden;
   border-top: 1px solid black;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
   font-family: 'Fresca', sans-serif;
 
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.maincontent {
 width: 1000px;
 margin:0 auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding-top: 25px;
}

.infotexta {
 text-align: center;
}

img {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.middlebar {
 height: 50px;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #edeff2;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.main-image-front {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
}
.topimage {
  position:absolute;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
 <title>placeholder</title> 
 <!-- css -->
 <link href="mainstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
 
  <body>
 <div class="topnav">
   <a href="#">Home</a>
   <a href="#">temp</a>
   <a href="#">temp</a>
   <a href="#">temp</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="topimage">
   <img src="/users/grecko/desktop/back.png" alt="topimage" class="main-image-front">
 </div>
 
 <div class="middlebar">
 
 </div>
   
 <div class="maincontent">
   <div class="maincontent-about infotexta">
   <h1>placeholder</h1>
   <p>your text hereyour text here<br>your text hereyour text here<br>your text hereyour text here<br>your text hereyour text here</p>
 </div>
```

This will allow you image to be displayed without the yellow bar showing up.